# How to view network activity across entire domain?

Tags: windows, networking, domain, bandwidth

Wondering if Windows Server 2008 R2 Std has any features that allow you to view network information like number of connections, current rate, total bytes, etc, for all computers on the domain? Separate info would be OK but ideally would like to view the entire list of PC's at once, in table layout..

Or is this only possible using 3rd party programs that must be installed across all systems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's called Performance Monitor. It's pretty heavyweight for that though. You'd do much better to use SNMP to monitor your switch ports, using a 3rd-party SNMP collector. There are plenty of free or paid ones. This way, you don't have to play around with the end-stations at all.

Keep the inventory of machine names->MAC addresses->switch CAM tables->ports updated, and you'll know which machines are using how much LAN bandwidth.

- Note - this does not mean monitoring of traffic bound to the internet. You'd have to be monitoring your router(s) or other border devices for that.